# onClick event of backbone view not returning current view/model

Tags: backbone.js, view, backbone-events

I have a view in Backbone where 'el' is the 'sample div of below. And in the render function of this view I'm creating dynamic `<li>` elements and appending those to the ul element.

```
var tabView = Backbone.View.extend({
         el : '#sample',
         $ul :  $("#sample").find("ul"),
...( Other code)
 render: function () {
  var htmContent = this.template(this.model.attributes);
  this.$ul.append(htmContent);
  return this.$el;
 }
```

```html
<div id="sample> 
<ul class="list">
<!-- <li class="series"> elements will be appended here'-->
</ul>
</div>
```

Now what I need to do is, at the click of an `<li>` element, I need to get the corresponding view of that element to get the model and call methods. So I have registered a hash event in this tabView and calling a method when the `<li>` is clicked. However below 'this' always returns the last created `<li>` elements view/model only.

```
events:{
         'click .series':'clickOnContent'
       }

clickOnContent: function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
    var val =  this.model.attributes;
}
```

How can I get the currently clicked `<li>` elements view/model instead?

Answer (score 1):

Your seem to be trying to use a model and its attributes to hold a set of list items. This is approach is incorrect. Instead you will need to create a sub-view for the list which is backed by a "collection" and each of the li elements should then be added to the list collection. Read one of the plentiful tutorials on Backbone Collections.